# Renderscript Carousel Example

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I don't have much experience with `Renderscript`, but I'm wanting to learn a little more. I found [this example from Google](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip), but I'm unsure how to actually load my own images into the carousel.

I'm confused about loading more than one image into the carousel, because it doesn't use an `Adapter`, but rather one `Bitmap` and I'm unsure how to go about changing this.

```
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.glossy_overlay);
```

I've done some research, but it's difficult to find solid examples for someone without much experience. Would someone provide some resources or an example of how I could load my own images into the carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define static List in CarouselTestActivity

```
private static final int[] DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST =
{ R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03,R.drawable.image04, R.drawable.image05,R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03,R.drawable.image04, R.drawable.image05}; }
```

Modify value

```
    private static final int TOTAL_CARDS =DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST.length ;
```

Modify getTexture in LocalCarouselViewHelper in the same class

@Override
        public Bitmap getTexture(int n) {

```
        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources()
                .getDrawable(DEFAULT_RESOURCE_LIST[n])).getBitmap();
        return bitmap;
        /*
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        mPaint.setColor(0x40808080);
        canvas.drawRect(2, 2, TEXTURE_WIDTH-2, TEXTURE_HEIGHT-2, mPaint);
        mPaint.setTextSize(100.0f);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
        canvas.drawText("" + n, 2, TEXTURE_HEIGHT-10, mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mGlossyOverlay, null,
                new Rect(PIXEL_BORDER, PIXEL_BORDER,
                        TEXTURE_WIDTH - PIXEL_BORDER, TEXTURE_HEIGHT - PIXEL_BORDER), mPaint);
        return bitmap;
        */
    }
```

Enjoy...